DBQUERY PRESTASHOP
I am having problems using dbquery to query my database,
When I run the following code:
<?php

$sql = new DbQuery();

$sql->select('*');

$sql->from('ps_orders', 'o');

print($results = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql));

?>

I get a 500 error from the server, I don't know if this is because the server is rejecting the SQL connection or I am doing something wrong in the code.
I've searched many forums but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please enable error_reporting or check the error logs to verify the actual error

500 errors are generic server errors and you'll need to check the server's logs for more information

The database prefix should not be entered.
The correct query is
<?php

$sql = new DbQuery();

$sql->select('*');

$sql->from('orders', 'o');

print($results = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql));

?>

